# finding highest contributing sub-band from wavelet packet tree?

Tags: matlab, wavelet

i'm working on adaptive sampling algorithm wharein the sampling rate selection solely depends on the frequency  sub-band..I have decomposed the signal into say 'j' levels resulting in 2^j sets of coefficients.. Now i need to find highest contributing sub-band found currently in the signal.

Comment: What do you mean by "highest contributing"?

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth.. Highest contributing in the sense that when signal is reconstructed using coefficients of sub-band at 'j' level results in best case estimation of original signal..

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your time-frequency tiling (i.e. structure of your wavelet tree). If it is a STFT like tree, then the maximum coefficient represents the highest contributing frequency band. In a DWT like tree, it is different. So you should check out what kind of a filter bank you are using first and its corresponding time-frequency tiling. You can check [this](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Discrete_Wavelet_Filterbank.html).

Comment: its a dwt like tree wherein signal is decomposed into sub-bands by recursively applying a pair of
Quadrature Mirror Filters (QMF). How to go about in selecting right sub-band using graphical user interface(Wavelet toolbox)?